# Add objective c to prism syntax highlighter

Tags: objective-c, wordpress, prism, syntax-highlighting

I recently started using the prism syntax highlighter (specifically syntax highlighter cb for Wordpress). How do add objective c to prism? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write a [language definition](http://prismjs.com/extending.html) describing Objective-C and add it to Prism's list of languages as shown in the examples on that page.